# Error converting data type varchar to bigint: INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting this error when trying to execute a stored procedure and am not sure why:

> Msg 8114:
> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Please see my SQL query below:

```
INSERT INTO StagingArea.dbo.DimStudentsTEST
       (StudentCode, Module, Year, UniqueStudentID)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        RTRIM(S.STUDENT_Student_ID) + 
            RTRIM(SUBSTRING(AY.ACADEMYR_Academic_Year_Code, 3, 2) +
            SUBSTRING(AY.ACADEMYR_Academic_Year_Code, 8, 2)) AS 'UniqueStudentID',
        ...
    FROM
        ...
    INNER JOIN
        ...
```

I believe the error is emerging because of the `UniqueStudentID` I have tried using CAST & CONVERT around the SELECT line but still no luck. Perhaps I am using in the wrong way. I have a feeling it is maybe because the column of the table I am pulling the data from ("AY.ACADEMYR..") is not of datatype 'bigint' so the error message keeps occuring. The datatype of the 'UniqueStudentID' column is of datatype 'bigint'

Can anyone see where the problem lies or if I am meant to use the CAST/CONVERT function then how best to use in this scenario.

Many thanks,

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. The error, however, can't be more clear. What about it don't you understand?

Comment: The colums in your `SELECT` need to be in the correct order of the `INSERT`. The names are ignored. Right now you're trying to stuff `UniqueStudentID` into `StudentCode`, which is probably not right.

Comment: Your insert statement lists `StudentCode` first, yet your select appears to be returning UniqueStudentID first; Simply fix your column ordering either in your select or your insert column list.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry I have made sure the INSERT and SELECT are in the same order...but its not in the same order of the actual table its inserting into (DimStudentsTEST)..does that make a difference?

Comment: @Stu Sorry I have made sure the INSERT and SELECT are in the same order...but its not in the same order of the actual table its inserting into (DimStudentsTEST)...does that make a difference? Should have made that clear in the query above

Comment: @Larnu I am not sure why its occuring when I have tried to convert the statement in the SELECT function to a bigint but still no luck

Comment: *I have made sure the INSERT and SELECT are in the same order* - not in your fragmented example you haven't, hence the comments here.

Comment: Which is why, again, I asked for sample data and expected results. We can't run your SQL, we don't have access to your instance, and without examples, we can't tell you why it's not working. Make an [mre].

Comment: @Stu Regarding the order though does it make a difference if the table in which the data in INSERTING INTO is not in the same order as the INSERT order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the columns are in the proper order during the `INSERT`.

I suspect you there may be some unexpected data/strings in the underlying components.

To identify the bogus records, try the following using `try_convert()`.  As you may know, `try_convert()` will return a NULL if the conversion fails.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  ...
 Where try_convert(bigint,RTRIM(S.STUDENT_Student_ID)+RTRIM(SUBSTRING(AY.ACADEMYR_Academic_Year_Code,3,2)+SUBSTRING(AY.ACADEMYR_Academic_Year_Code,8,2))) is null
```

Comment: Hi, you were completely right! There were characters referenced in the column which forced it into a datatype varchar. Apologies for the delayed response I tried this very late yesterday. Thank you again

Comment: @Daisy Always happy to help.   Pleased you identified the problem